# Algorithm.h and Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c++

since I'd like to use some functions in algorithm.h in my Objective-C file, I changed the extension of such file to .mm to use Objective-C++.

Anyway, when I include the algorithm.h file the compiler tells me that can't find that file:

I tried:

```
#include <algorithm.h>
#include <algorithm>
#import <algorithm.h>
#import <algorithm>
```

but I get always the same error.
I'm using Xcode 4.3 and Lion. 
Any advice?

Comment: Hmm. `#include <algorithm>` and `#import <algorithm>` both ought to work. I'm wondering if you might need the XCode "command line tools" to get the standard C++ headers - you can install them from Preferences -> Downloads.

Comment: Another thing to check would be if the file algorithm is in /usr/include/c++/*/ - if it is, your include paths in the project settings are messed up.

Comment: thanks pmjordan the problem was that I've to install the command line tools ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We worked out the solution in the comments:

It seems that a default XCode install doesn't include the C++ standard library headers - you have to install the *Command Line Tools* package via the **Preferences** -> **Downloads** dialog.

The standard-compliant header is `<algorithm>` without the .h. I don't see any reason why `#import` shouldn't work (versus `#include`).